# Need Help ... Android Studio send data to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, android-studio, controller, token

We have created an Android application with a WebView that allows us to access our website, code in php Laravel. We would like to send push notifications with Firebase to a specific user on Android. Our problem is to send the user's token to one of the controllers of the website to save it on our MySql database. Do you have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Do you have tried anythings??

Comment: No, because have no idea how to do it. I new in android and php! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the Webview's Uri just add the user's token as a GET param. 
Then get it from backend with Laravel.

Comment: can you show me a exemple of GET ... it's on android studio or php?

Comment: webview.loadUrl("https://example.com/?token=" + userToken); Then in laravel you can get the value by simply:         $userToken = $request->input('token');